# overlay images over images in a footer with css

Tags: css, image, overlay

So i have a footer containing 8 images (4 buttons and 4 icons) the idea is to display each  of the 4 icons over the respective button. If I use `position:relative` , they are just displayed one near the other, so 8 images separated, while it has to look like there are only 4 images.

This is what I want to get: [image]

This is what I get instead: [image]

My css:

```
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
}
    #footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 90%;
        height: 10%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
        left: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    #footer img {
        height: 100%;
    }
```

my html:

```
<div id="footer">
   <img class="absolute" src="img/back.png" />
   <img src="img/empty_circle_button.png" />
   <img class="absolute" src="img/gems_btn.png" />
   <img src="img/empty_circle_button.png" />
   <img class="absolute" src="img/up.png" />
   <img src="img/empty_circle_button.png" />
   <img class="absolute" src="img/missions.png"  />
   <img src="img/empty_circle_button.png" />
</div>
```

I also need this to be valid in a webview. Any suggestion on what's wrong here?

Comment: you need to remove position absolute on the mix here, and if you want to used anyway, you have to at least give left and top properties, but in this context, using position absolute with a position fixed div as a parent, absolute will not works as expected

Comment: empty_circle should be clearly a background here

Comment: If I remove position absolute, I get icons near buttons instead over buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution by myself:

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
   <div><img src="img/back.png" /></div>
   <div><img src="img/gems_btn.png" /></div>
   <div><img src="img/up.png" /></div>
   <div><img src="img/missions.png" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 90%;
    height: 10%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    left: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#footer div {
    background-image: url(../img/empty_circle_button.png);
    background-size: contain;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#footer div img {
    height: 100%;
}
```